# Multi touch in kivy issues

Tags: slider, kivy, reset, multi-touch

Actually I'm working on an application in kivy and the main part is using 2 sliders that are able to reset to its initial state when released.

ISSUE here is: Both the sliders are being used. When one is released, the other one is also going back to its initial state. Is there any way to overcome this

Comment: Welcome to [so] Susheel. You should add a [mcve]. It is difficult to help you without seeing the code you are using. Best regards.

Comment: So this my code .. ISSUE is : If one slider is released, the other one is also going back to initial condition.
-----
'''        
self.velocity = Slider(min=-100, max =100, value=0, orientation='vertical')

        self.steering = Slider(min=-100, max=100, value=0)
   
        self.add_widget(self.steering)

        self.add_widget(self.velocity)        

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):  

                self.clear_widgets()

                self.__init__()
'''

Comment: sorry the code has messed up like that in comment..

Comment: Susheel edit the question (`edit` button) and use `{}` button to format the code.

Comment: @SusheelSelvamani please paste the code if you are still having this problem.  I am encountering it too

Comment: Dude, there is no way. Just plan something around it.